# Dialogflow CX phone gateway - Extract caller ID

Tags: dialogflow-cx

In Dialogflow CX, I have used phone gateway. I want extract the caller ID of the user who calls the voice bot. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/phone-gateway#caller-id), we can get the caller id from the payload field in webhook. But I dont see a payload field or caller id in the request in webhook. How can I extract the customer phone number who calls? Thanks in advance.

To understand the problem better, here is the sample code that just prints the contents of the request:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(force=True)
    print(req)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

[The contents of the request is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iS23.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the **caller_id** value from the [payload](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.QueryParameters.FIELDS.google.protobuf.Struct.google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.QueryParameters.payload) field in the [webhook request](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#webhookrequest). Note that the webhook should be enabled as it’s required to retrieve the ***telephony*** field.

Here’s an example webhook code using Node.js to log the **caller_id** for Dialogflow CX Phone Gateway from your webhook request:

```
console.log('Caller ID' + JSON.stringify(request.body.payload.telephony));
```

Result:

[image: Caller ID]

Comment: I am using Python code. When I print out the entire request, it does not contain telephony nor payload field. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with retrieving the caller ID from Dialogflow CX Phone Gateway. You may check this Google Group conversation for [reference](https://groups.google.com/g/dialogflow-cx-edition-users/c/YgdRpX6qjI8). You may also consider filing this via [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/getting-support#issues) for Dialogflow CX.